# How to create a executable file(.sh) in linux that will copy and paste file

Tags: linux, sh

How to create a .sh file that will copy and paste files?

I created a script.sh file with the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
tar -pzvxf file1.tar (to unzip)
cp -a /root/Desktop/file1/. /root/Desktop/Destination (copy)
```

After which I `./script.sh` to run it but it wouldn't run.
Any idea why?

Comment: About all languages can do that.

Comment: What about in linux? Can u show an example?

Comment: Do you even know what an executable file is ? -I mean, have you ever tried opening one in your editor ? An executable is a binary file. You can't edit it directly, you have to use another language to create it. C, C++, Python, Java, R, Perl, PHP, Even JavaScript can do this. Please read the [help/dont-ask]

Comment: I tried editing the bat file move "folder" "D:\destination" only those file in the folder is copied but those other folders in the folder is not copied. Any idea why?

Comment: Edit your post by adding : what you already tried, what you got, what you want to do, add the corresponding tags

Comment: @Jayh Please check if you have extracted tar file in desktop itself. Also use this
`cp -a /root/Desktop/file1/  /root/Desktop/Destination (copy)` remove dot from between path. It will find root from the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the script has it's executable bit set.
Try using this in your shell.

```
chmod +x ./script.sh
```

This will ensure that the script can be executed by your shell.